# how to check if the three dates in a table column has continuous months

Tags: select, oracle11g, to-char

i have a table that has a column name date_tran that shows the date on which the user has made any transaction. is there any way how i can check if 3 transactions are made by the user is in the same month or 3 continuos month?

i am using the following snippet:

```
SELECT CUST_ID,  DATE_TRAN FROM  FAKE_CUST F WHERE 
          EXISTS( 
                SELECT 1 from FAKE_CUST where (TO_CHAR(DATE_TRAN,'MM') = TO_CHAR(F.DATE_TRAN,'MM')-1 OR TO_CHAR(DATE_TRAN,'MM') = TO_CHAR(F.DATE_TRAN,'MM')) AND 
                                        CUST_ID= F.CUST_ID  AND TO_CHAR(DATE_TRAN,'YYYY')=TO_CHAR(F.DATE_TRAN,'YYYY'))
      and exists(
                SELECT 1 from FAKE_CUST where (TO_CHAR(DATE_TRAN,'MM') = TO_CHAR(F.DATE_TRAN,'MM')-2 OR TO_CHAR(DATE_TRAN,'MM') = TO_CHAR(F.DATE_TRAN,'MM')) AND 
                                        CUST_ID= F.CUST_ID AND TO_CHAR(DATE_TRAN,'YYYY')=TO_CHAR(F.DATE_TRAN,'YYYY'))
```

but is is showing all the entries in the table and not the required result.

Answer (score 0):

1. To Get 3 transactions are made by the user in the same month

   Something like... Group By getmonth(DATE_TRN) having count(getmonth(DATE_TRN)) >= 3

MySql :

SELECT CUST_ID, DATE_TRAN  FROM XXX where cust_id in
(SELECT cust_id from XXX Group By DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TRAN, '%m') having count(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TRAN, '%m')) > 2)

1. To Get 3 transactions are made by the user in 3 cons months

   Group By getmonth(DATE_TRN) having count(getmonth(DATE_TRN)) > 1, count(getmonth(DATE_TRN)-1) > 1, count(getmonth(DATE_TRN)-2) > 1

Comment: i am writing the query in oracle. I modified your query to but this is not working

Comment: SELECT CUST_ID, DATE_TRAN FROM fake_cust where cust_id in ( SELECT cust_id from fake_cust Group By EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE_TRaN) having ( count(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE_TRAN)) > 1 AND count(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE_TRAN)-1) > 1 AND count(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE_TRAN)-2) > 1 ) )